# Добавить код после 3 результатов foreach

Tags: php, битрикс

Есть цикл выводящий элементы каталога:

```
foreach ($arResult['ITEMS'] as $key => $arItem)
{
```

После 3 результатов нужно добавить изображение и продолжить вывод. 
Как проверить что уже выведено 3 элемента и добавить код?

Comment: После _первых_ 3 или после _каждых_ 3?

Comment: Что в переменной key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у вас `$key` числовое значение и они идут по порядку, то можно просто сделать.

**После каждых 3**

```
 foreach ( $arResult[ 'ITEMS' ] as $key => $arItem ) {
    if ( $key % 3 == 0 ) {

        /*тут код*/

    }
 }
```

**После первых 3**

```
 foreach ( $arResult[ 'ITEMS' ] as $key => $arItem ) {
        if ( $key == 2) {

            /*тут код*/

        }
     }
```

Comment: А если `$arResult[ 'ITEMS' ]` - ассоциативный массив?

Comment: При условии >2 будет выводить ещё и после четвёртой, пятой и так далее. А нужно только после третьей. Нужно просто == 2

Comment: @NikolajSarry,  спасибо,  сам не заметил ))

Comment: @hindmost в вопросе нет условия что будет ассоциативный массив, если задающий добавит такое условие, конечно отредактирую свой ответ.

Answer (score 2):

А если $key нечисловое, то можно сделать с помощью переменной-счётчика:

**после первых трёх:**

```
foreach ($arResult['ITEMS'] as $key => $arItem) {
  $i++;
  echo $arItem;
  if ($i == 3) {
     echo <картинка>;
  }
}
```

**после каждых трёх:**

```
foreach ($arResult['ITEMS'] as $key => $arItem) {
  $i++;
  echo $arItem;
  if ($i % 3 == 0) {
     echo <картинка>;
  }
}
```

Comment: И будет после каждых трех, а не первых.

Comment: @NikolajSarry, а в вопросе и не сказано, что только после ПЕРВЫХ трёх